# Squid Proxy - Forward Port 21000 to 80

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm looking to forward traffic coming in on port 21000 to get redirected to 80 and then flow back through the proxy (80 back to 21000). How do you configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't a better way to handle this be through IPTables?

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp -d {some host} --dport 21000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 80

Comment: How do I try this out. And then undo this if it doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: How does iptables help me forward traffic from browsers hitting this machine? iptables is only for outbound traffic from this box correct? It wouldn't provide me with the proxy functionality correct?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It appears that you are wanting to have the user go to port 21000 through your machine, and then on the other side actually hit port 80. Is there a particular reason you wish to mask the port? Are you wanting to proxy, or do you want to just route?

Comment: It is for a customer that needs to hit our service on port 80. They get charged for traffic on port 80 but not other ports. I'm just trying to pass http traffic through a machine ("proxy") to our server on the other side and back. So given this would iptables work? Our server in the middle would be hosted on EC2.

Comment: You could do with adding this to your question.  Three different machines in three different locations will make a big difference to the answers.

Comment: @Tyndall: iptables can be used to control both incoming and outgoing (forwarded and originated) traffic. You can allow/deny, change source /destination IPs, etc..

Comment: @gdurham or others, how could I undo this command if it doesn't work or I need to change the config at a later date?

Comment: You can use iptables -D {the above rule} to delete.